# Comparing ArrayList values with Intergers

Tags: arraylist

My statement is returning that the value of x is 0 but it is clearly 5.

The return Statement is
"5" and "yeah"

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DeletionEasyTester {
    public static void main(String Args[]){
        int x = 1;
    ArrayList<Integer> list1 =  new ArrayList<>();  
    list1.add(3);
    list1.add(5);
    list1.add(8);
    list1.add(0);
    list1.add(2);
    list1.add(5);
    list1.add(4);
    x = list1.get(1);
    System.out.println(x);
    if(x == 0);
    {
        System.out.print("yeah");
    }


    }


}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this locally.  Are you sure we are looking at the same code you are?

Comment: What does it return for you locally?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here: `if(x == 0);`. It should be `if(x == 0)`, without `;`.

In your version of the code, there is an empty code block after the if statement, and `System.out.print("yeah");` is in a block unrelated to the if-statement.